# reflecting changes made to the datagrid back on the dataset and the datatable

Tags: c#

i have a datagrid which has a dataset as its datasource and that dataset contains a table from a database.what i need is when i make changes to cell values in datagrid, the changes should also reflect back on the database. the thing is these changes do get reflected on the dataset but when i use da.Update(ds,"TableName") to forward that changes to database,it does not work. The database still shows the old value even though the datagrid and dataset shows the updated value. 
i have used the da.Update() command twice in the same program at other places and there it seems to work properly and the database shows the updated value. i dont know wats causing it to not work this time. wats suprising is that i am not even getting any errors, the code executes properly but no changes are seen in the database.
someone kindly help!!!

**edit:** actually, what i am doing is i am selecting a row from a datagrid and then displaying all the cell values from that row on textboxes. then i am editing those values and saving them using foll. code

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dgDetails.SelectedCells[0].Value = txtPurpose.Text;
   da.Update(ds, "Scheduler");
}

no one has the solution for the problem????

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same data adapter for both the fill and the update method call? I believe that for the most part you need to call the fill and update methods from the same data adapter.

Also, make sure you're not calling AcceptChanges before calling Update. AcceptChanges will change the state of the dataset to unchanged.

There's a good example of accomplishing what you're looking to do at http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3801/web-forms-datagrid-and-dataset-programming/6/

Comment: ya, i am using the same data adapter to fill and update and also i am not caling ds.AcceptChanges() before da.update(), i am calling it after i do da.update()

Comment: i saw that link but the thing is i can see the changes in my dataset, the only problem is that changes are not forwarded to database through da.update() even though there seems to be no problem with the da.update() as it works fine when i am previously using it.

Comment: Well, you don't need to call AcceptChanges at all. I believe it's called by Update itself. Have you checked to see if the dataset believes that there have been updates that need to be persisted? I'd check the value of HasChanges on the dataset to see if the changes are being tracked properly. It could be that HasChanges is false and as a result the call to Update isn't doing anything.

Comment: can u plz tell where do i need to call HasChanges i.e. before or after da.update()?

Comment: i tried calling HasChanges before update and am getting the value as false. so how do i make it true???

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't have your code in front of me. The basic reason behind your issue is that the dataset doesn't seem to be tracking the changes that are made through the datagrid. I'd run back through the examples available on the web and make sure your implementation matches the examples.